# strpos() not working with negative offset

Tags: php, strpos

I have a strange one, probably something silly, but I have been racking my brains for far too long on it.

I am using strpos() to see if a string ends with a certain substring, by using a negative offset of the length of said substring as per the PHP documentation. Which performs the search x chatacters from the end of the haystack, supposedly.

```
var_dump($recipient); //debug
if(strpos( $recipient, '_redacted', -9 ) === FALSE) {
   // do stuff
}
```

It just complains that the offset is not contained in the string. Yet the output is :

> string(29) "fullname@company.tld_redacted"
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity:    Warning
> Message:     strpos(): Offset not contained in string

One can clearly see that the string is much longer than 9 characters, so why is it throwing that warning?(and by extension returning FALSE and always triggering my condition  - incorrectly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Support for negative offsets was added in PHP 7.1.
You're likely running an older version.
Always see the **Changelog** section on [the manual page](http://php.net/strpos).

Comment: Great spot. This test platfrom is on 7.02. Knew it would be something silly.

Answer (score 1):

Use [strrpos](https://php.net/strrpos) instead of [strpos](https://php.net/strpos).

Answer (score -2):

you could try changing the logic of your if statement thus

```
var_dump($recipient); //debug
if(strpos( $recipient, '_redacted') === strlen($recipient) - 9) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Try that and let me know if it works for you

Comment: I'd think `substr($recipient, -9) == '_redacted'` would be much less cumbersome…

Comment: I'd like to know why my answer was down voted? it is a valid option just not as elegant.